# use more no of batteries for more current for servos,why using motor shield?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-motor-shield

motor driver is for current amplification.for that we could connect more batteries to servos to get more current.but why are we using motor shields?

Comment: Questions on this site must be clearly stated and specific.  Perhaps you should read a bit about the difference between radio control type servos which have their own drive electronics, vs. DC motors that do not and so need external drivers.  Also you cannot simply connect more batteries to most servos - they have voltage limits!

Comment: Because science.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the advantage of using a motor shield if I want to use a stepper motor?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1439/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-a-motor-shield-if-i-want-to-use-a-stepper-motor)

Answer (score 2):

The motor shield is useful because you cannot pass the required amount of current through Arduino's microcontroller without blowing it up.

Of course you don't need to use the motor shield if you create a similar circuit of your own that performs the same task.